# How to use material icons in panelbar

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Iam able to show kendoui webfont icons in panelbar. but could not show material font icons.Can any explain how to use material-font icons in PanelBar of kendoui angular2

Comment: Did you tried this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/icon ?

Comment: yes im able to show material icons in other  areas of application.In panelbar im not able to show                                                                                                                <kendo-panelbar-item title="Customer" icon="camera">

                           </kendo-panelbar-item>                                       camera is kendo font-icon. my question is how to give material icon there?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [developer guide for the material icons](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) to add them to your page. Once loaded, the icons can be nested in the PanelBar content using the standard markup (`<i class="material-icons">face</i>`). See [this Plunkr snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kx6GZ37cVhXj9ca3xqGt?p=preview).

Comment: thanks for the help i'm able to get icons inside the panel bar content .can i get the icons on the left of header i.e for example to the left of My Team mates & Projects in your given plunkr code

Comment: I am afraid that at this time the PanelBar does not support templates for its item rendering -- you can [suggest this in the kendo-angular2 repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues). You could hack around this via custom classes, though -- see the [updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kx6GZ37cVhXj9ca3xqGt?p=preview)